# efficiently compute percentages in hive or sql

Tags: sql, hive

```
SELECT
      (CASE WHEN tag=FRAUD THEN 0
      ELSE 1 END) fraud_tag,
      COUNT(DISTINCT account_id) AS distinct_account_count
    FROM fraud_tags a
    GROUP BY
      (CASE WHEN c.name='riskclass_NotFraud' THEN 0
      ELSE 1 END)
RESULT
fraud_tag   distinct_account_count
    0            100
    1            500
```

Now I want to compute fraud_percentages, number of distinct accounts with fraud_tag=0 over total number of accounts. I have to do it two steps. Any suggestions to make it more efficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to do this with the values in one row:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT case when tag = FRAUD then account_id end) as distinct_fraud,
       COUNT(DISTINCT case when tag = FRAUD then NULL else account_id end) as distinct_notfraud,
       (COUNT(DISTINCT case when tag = FRAUD then account_id end)*1.0/count(distinct account_id)
       ) as fraud_rate
    FROM fraud_tags ft;
```